# how to store multiple radio button values to mysql in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am beginner in php and trying to create a attendance management system. 
I have printed the student details from a DB along with attendance "PRESENT OR ABSENT" in a radio button. I don't understand how to give unique name to radio buttons since I fetch them in array so i used 'ROLLNO'  as radio button name since it differs from student to student.. here is the code of it. and

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                     {

        echo "<strong>Roll No</strong> :".$row["RollNo"]."&nbsp"."<strong>Name</strong> :".$row["Name"]."&nbsp"."<strong>Attendance</strong> :"."<input type ='radio' name = '".$row['RollNo']."' value = 'present'>Present<br> <input type ='radio' name = '".$row['RollNo']."' value = 'absent'>absent<br>";  

    }
```

The other issue is i don't understand how to write them to database again for storing all the student details including attendance at once. I am able to store it for a single student using a sql query but not able to do it for multiple students.

Comment: the values should be different then only you will store for all the students

Comment: which value should be different ? if you mean the radio button value , then yes its different. cause each student have different roll no and i am using it to for radio button name.

Comment: you have given the   value='absent' and value='present' change this to value='".$row['RollNo']."'

Comment: if so then the radio box will have roll no as values , i don't want that. i am giving rollno as radio box names just to separate them. I want 'PRESENT AND ABSENT' as values to store them in DB

Comment: can you show the entire code you have tired

Comment: This is the link of code which fetches the details from DB and shows it in the html form . I want a idea to store the data along with the attendance value to another DB for multiple students. P.S : I am a beginner
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uhVDzWp90TFeu4ut9b3cDeCtwJEagrwcZHj7cvvRBtA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: make the name as array  then you can get the multiple values through post